# iOS 11 URLSessionDataTask's progress variable is not showing right progress

Tags: ios, ios11, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to find out progress of an upload task. But I can only use the URLSession's `dataTask` method (instead of `uploadTask` method) to create the task. I can't use delegate initializer to create the session also. To find the progress I'm using KVO on the URLSessionDataTask's progress variable as in the code below.

But I'm getting KVO value starting from 0.95 only (not from 0). Appreciate any help on how to find the progress in this case.

I'm using [this sample code](https://github.com/simplyi/ImageUploadExampleWithProgressBar), and changed it for my needs:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate  {
    private var progressKVOContext = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var uploadButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageUploadProgressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyHashable: Any])
    {
        myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        uploadImage()

    }

    func uploadImage()
    {
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1)

        if(imageData == nil )  { return }

        self.uploadButton.isEnabled = false


        let uploadScriptUrl = URL(string:"http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-post-example-script/")
        var request = URLRequest(url: uploadScriptUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, urlResp, error) in
            print("\(String(describing: data))")
        }
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            task.progress.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Progress.fractionCompleted), options: [.new], context: &progressKVOContext)
            print("KVO set here")

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if context == &progressKVOContext && keyPath == #keyPath(Progress.fractionCompleted), let progress = object as? Progress {
            var progressFractionCompleted = (progress.totalUnitCount == -1) ? 1.0 : progress.fractionCompleted

            if progressFractionCompleted == 1 {
                print("progressFractionCompleted here = \(progressFractionCompleted)")

//                try? removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Progress.fractionCompleted), context: &progressKVOContext)
            }

            if progressFractionCompleted > 1 {
                print("Inside greater \(progressFractionCompleted)")
                progressFractionCompleted = 1/progressFractionCompleted
            }
            print("progressFractionCompleted = \(progressFractionCompleted)")
        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: I used sessionDataTask for KVO and then used the progress.